# How to fix the IE issue 'parentNode' is null or not an object with Ext.js3.1.1?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, extjs, extjs3

I got this issue trying to destroy an Extjs 3.1.1 window on IE. The error says:

- On IE8:  'parentNode' is null or not an object
- On IE9: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'insertBefore': object is null or undefined 
  ext-all-debug.js, line 5533 character 10

It works fine for other browsers.

The exceptions is raised on this method:
[Ext.element:insertAfter()](http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.1.1/docs/source/Element.insertion.html#method-Ext.Element-insertAfter)

And the stack trace is similar to [this closed thread](http://webtest.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?115507-IE-Ext.Panel-removeAll%28%29-error-gt-parentNode-is-null-or-not-an-object)

The component hierarchy looks like this (some components were extended):

`window > panel > EditorGrid > FormPanel > Combobox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This patch fixed my issue. It just overrides the function adding checks for `parentNode` before calling its method. I added this code snippet to a fixes.js file that runs after Extjs.

```
Ext.override(Ext.Element, {

    /**
    * Inserts this element after the passed element in the DOM
    * @param {Mixed} el The element to insert after
    * @return {Ext.Element} this
    *
    * @overrides  to fix IE issue of "parentNode null or not an object".
    */
    insertAfter: function(el){
        el = Ext.getDom(el);
        if (el && el.parentNode) {
            el.parentNode.insertBefore(this.dom, el.nextSibling);
        }
        return this;
    }
});
```

Please note that ideally I should investigate why the `element`'s `parentNode` is null, but this fix was good enough for me. Probably one of the extended element is destroying sub-items before the window is destroyed.

Comment: It seems to me that that is a bug in the library, elements don't necessarily have a parent (e.g. document element).

Comment: Possibly. The [API for Ext.Element class](http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.1.1/docs/?class=Ext.Element) doesn't specify about the `parentNode`.